# ASP.NET MVC Multiselect ListBox is not selecting multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my Model Class

```
public class OperationStudyInputViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<string> AttachmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult OperationStudyInput()
{
    var attachmentList = _dbContext.AttachmentAndFolders
        .Where(x => x.IsAttachementOrFolder == "Attachment")
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            x.AttchmentFolderId,
            x.Name
        }).ToList();
    ViewBag.AttachmentList = new MultiSelectList(attachmentList, "AttchmentFolderId", "Name");
}
```

Here is View :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttachmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AttachmentId,(MultiSelectList)ViewBag.AttachmentList)
</div>
```

MultiSelet Textbox is rendering properly but it selecting only one value, its not selecting multiple value.

**Cannot identify where the problem actually is!! Any Help Please!!**

Comment: What do you mean _selecting only value_?

Comment: Its selecting only one value..If I try to select another value after selecting one, the previous selection is being lost.

Comment: Not related, but suggest you just use `ViewBag.AttachmentList = dbContext.AttachmentAndFolders.Where(...).Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.AttchmentFolderId, Text = x.Name });` and `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AttachmentId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AttachmentList)`

Comment: What your claiming is not possible - your code generates a `<select multiple="multiple" ... >` element. Do you have any javascript that is altering the behavior?

Comment: May be Not!! By the way should I hold down the control button to select multiple or just clicking serially on individual...??

Comment: Yes, to select multiple items you need to hold down the CTRL (or SHIFT) key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiselect List Boxes require that you hold down Ctrl to select multiple items.